# when the characters in the text box is more than 3 i need to add border

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

- when the characters in the text box is more than 3 i need to add border to the texbox.
- so I added className wholeContainer
- not sure when to add state and setState. do I need to create state ever for class name in css
- can you guys tell me how to fix it.
- providing it below.

https://jsfiddle.net/q7yvmsa3/14/

```or-tag-here
class TwitterBox extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { enteredTextBoxvalue : '' };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({enteredTextBoxvalue: event.target.value});   
    console.log((event.target.value).legth);

    if((event.target.value).legth > 3) {    
        this.setState({className : wholeContainer});
        //console.log("long characters");
    }
  }

    render() {
        return (<div>Hello {this.props.name}
                        <textarea className={this.state.className}
                value={this.state.enteredTextBoxvalue}
                onChange = {this.handleChange}>
                            there should be only 140 characters
                    </textarea>
        </div>);
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <TwitterBox name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: if((event.target.value).legth > 3) {  => **length** is not spelled correctly. It's likely causing error, can you check the console?

Comment: `this.setState({className : wholeContainer});` is the problem. The rest of your code works except the spelling mistake as suggested by Paul. Hence wholeContainer is not defined.

Comment: @almostabeginner hey but the textbox is getting the red color...only if I click outside

Comment: That's a browser compatibility issue. Tested it in IE 11 and it works, but tested it in Chrome, and it doesn't. Chrome still works, but the blue color of selected input box isn't removed. You can see the color change, that is because the red is applied, but 'selected input box style' isn't overridden.

Comment: Here's an example of its behavior in chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/cfztjbyq/

Answer (score 2):

So, fix the length and add quotes around wholeContainer. These two changes worked for me at the fiddle.

```
if((event.target.value).length > 3) {    
    this.setState({className : 'wholeContainer'});
```

On a side note, there was another unrelated error, just so you know:
(not sure if it's related to fiddle, or part of your handling)

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/ Line 85
return (<div>Hello {this.props.name}
========^
```

Fiddle image:

[image]

Comment: updated the code in the fiddle but still I am dont see border color for the text box https://jsfiddle.net/q7yvmsa3/19/

Comment: Added image for how it looks to me in the fiddle.

Comment: hey but the textbox is getting the red color...only if I click outside

Comment: Interesting... I don't know, I only typed the four characters shown in the box (note the that the cursor is still in the text area), and the border turns red for me after the 'f' is typed?  I just tried again, and the behavior ias the same. What browser are you using? (I'm using FF)

Comment: I am using chrome

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the original issue is fixed as per Paul T's answer, regarding cross browser functionality, you can use the following edit:

https://jsfiddle.net/c9zv7yf5/

JS:

```
class TwitterBox extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { enteredTextBoxvalue : '' };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

    }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({enteredTextBoxvalue: event.target.value});   

    if((event.target.value).length > 3) {

        this.setState({className : 'wholeContainer'});
        //console.log("long characters");

    }
  }




    render() {
        return (<div>Hello {this.props.name}
                        <textarea className={this.state.className}
                value={this.state.enteredTextBoxvalue}
                onChange = {this.handleChange}>
                            there should be only 140 characters
                    </textarea>
        </div>);
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <TwitterBox name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

css:

```
.wholeContainer {
  outline: none !important;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<script src="https://facebook.github.io/react/js/jsfiddle-integration-babel.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional cross-browser info. Glad I asked which browser, for I wasn't immediately sure why the OP didn't see what I did (generally assuming same browser use). Voting up!

Comment: Have I used state and set state correctly... I am confused

Comment: @texirv yes, the problem was that you didn't pass a string to className, hence the quotation around wholeContainer.

Comment: Hey do I need to use any methods of component life cycle